# Pyramid login and logout page return 404, the rest of the app works fine

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm new to Pyramid and I'm following this guide:
http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki2/authorization.html

In Django, Views and URLs either worked or they crashed, but I've never run into a situation where a webpage that's clearly defined in both the views.py and urls.py would come up with a 404 error, this never happened to me. If there was something wrong with either of them it would crash, not throw a 404.

I'm building a wiki page to get the swing of things on Pyramid but I've hit a wall before I can move on with the tutorial.

I have my *init*.py file setup like this:

```
def main(global_config, **settings):

    engine = engine_from_config(settings, 'sqlalchemy.')
    DBSession.configure(bind=engine)
    Base.metadata.bind = engine

    authn_policy = AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy(
        'sosecret', callback=groupfinder, hashalg='sha512')
    authz_policy = ACLAuthorizationPolicy()

    config = Configurator(settings=settings,
                          root_factory='tutorial.models.RootFactory')

    config.set_authentication_policy(authn_policy)
    config.set_authorization_policy(authz_policy)

    config.include('pyramid_chameleon')
    config.add_static_view('static', 'static', cache_max_age=3600)
    config.add_route('view_wiki', '/')
    config.add_route('view_page', '/{pagename}')
    config.add_route('add_page', '/add_page/{pagename}')
    config.add_route('edit_page', '/{pagename}/edit_page')
    config.add_route('login', '/login')
    config.add_route('logout', '/logout')

    config.scan()
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

And my views.py file is setup like this:

```
@view_config(route_name='login', renderer='templates/login.pt')
@forbidden_view_config(renderer='templates/login.pt')
def login(request):
    login_url = request.route_url('login')
    referrer = request.url
    if referrer == login_url:
        referrer = '/' # never use the login form itself as came_from
    came_from = request.params.get('came_from', referrer)
    message = ''
    login = ''
    password = ''
    if 'form.submitted' in request.params:
        login = request.params['login']
        password = request.params['password']
        if USERS.get(login) == password:
            headers = remember(request, login)
            return HTTPFound(location = came_from,
                             headers = headers)
        message = 'Failed login'

    return dict(
        message = message,
        url = request.application_url + '/login',
        came_from = came_from,
        login = login,
        password = password,
        )

@view_config(route_name='logout')
def logout(request):
    headers = forget(request)
    return HTTPFound(location = request.route_url('view_wiki'),
                     headers = headers)
```

And so far the application runs great, but the login and logout are just completely void. I should at LEAST get a crash with a stack trace but I'm just given a flat out 404 ERROR...

I shut down the app and reran `pserve development.ini --reload` and nothing.... they're just not there....

I put this in my URL:

> 0.0.0.0:6446/FrontPage **<== WORKS**
>
> 0.0.0.0:6446/login **<== 404 Not Found, The resource could not be found. No such page**

I'm not really sure how to debug something that claims to be non existant... What could be the problem? I'm keeping all the templates in the same location and I'm comparing the edit_page view with the login view and they're extremely identical, but login doesn't exist apparently.... Why?

Answer (score 5):

Try put login before `/{pagename}`. This route system is stop on first match is encounter and process this. Invert all other pages start with static string (Ex.: `/foo`)

```
config.add_route('login', '/login')
config.add_route('logout', '/logout')
config.add_route('add_page', '/add_page/{pagename}')
config.add_route('view_page', '/{pagename}')
config.add_route('edit_page', '/{pagename}/edit_page')
```

Comment: The tutorial adds both routes before - http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki2/authorization.html#seeing-our-changes

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes this issue occurs when the function names are same, which usually happens when we copy paste a snippet of code and edit the same.

Say for example

Login view

```
@view_config(route_name='login', renderer='templates/login.pt') 
@forbidden_view_config(route_name='login')
def my_view(request):
```

Home page

```
@view_config(route_name='home', renderer='templates/mytemplate.pt')
def my_view(request):
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10952567)

Comment: @Phani  - I am pretty new to the business. I will follow your thoughts. It makes sense once you get reputation and then sharing the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

For debugging try using [proutes from the commandline](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/commandline.html#displaying-application-routes). It will tell you what routes pyramid has found.
Another great option is to [use/enable pyramid_debugtoolbar](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/master/quick_tour.html#easier-development-with-debugtoolbar) to debug any aspect of your application.

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure that your method or class names (whichever you use) are not duplicated. I got this error and it was due to copy/pasting the method without changing its **def** name.

Ex:

```
@view_config(route_name='login')
def logout(request):
    pass

@view_config(route_name='logout')
def logout(request):
    pass
```

will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing happen.  I think for me it was that I did not have a `/` directory, but you seem to have that covered.  So perhaps your wiki_view wasn't set up correctly.

Also,

-make sure that views receive the request.
-make sure that all the required packages are imported at the beginning of the files.

That solved it for me